# How to calculate the covariance of two binomial random variables?

Tags: variables, probability, covariance, probability-distribution

Let X~Bi(n,p) and Y~Bi(n,q) where X and Y are not independent. I want to calculate Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] but I don't know how to calculate the first term, E[XY].

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should ask this question on stats.stackexchange.com, rather than here.

Comment: Your question is a bit like asking: I have two vectors that are not at right angles; what is the angle between them? Depending on how X and Y are correlated, there are many possible values of Cov(X,Y).